Topology and parity in divergence free vector fields
If you consider a general divergence free vector field (not constant), in 2 and 3 dimensions it is easy to see that it is an axial vector and hence is not invariant under parity transformation (flip of one axis). I am very ignorant about topology, but I guess that one should be able to generalize this argument to arbitrary dimensions using some topological arguments. Any clue?

Unfortunately, what you are looking for cannot exist, because your premised are incorrect in several different ways.  One is that in two dimensions, axial vectors do not exist as distinct objects; instead, parity transformations are equivalent to $\pi$ rotations; flipping just one axis is not a parity transformation.  Moreover, axial vectors in three dimensions are invariant under parity, while it is polar vectors that are not.  Finally, an electrostatic field in vacuum is a polar vector with zero divergence, meaning that there is no connection between parity behavior and divergencelessness.
